# Tool for periodic table 3D graph?

Tags: 3d

[image]
Nature Reviews Materials volume 4, pages331–348(2019)

Hi
I want to draw a 3D graph on top of the periodic table like the picture above.
Is there any program that I could just put data in or any tools that can help me to draw a graph as similar as possible?

Comment: Here is a way to do this in R, but it requires advanced R plotting skills: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794236/ggplot2-3d-bar-plot Also see this, even more advanced: [plot3D package](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization)

Comment: The obvious question is what do the heights represent?

Answer (score 1):

Free [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) *Calc*, available for most operating systems, has a 3D Look Bar Chart option. Likely, MS Word *Excel* has similar options.

That said, the chart in your example shows perspective, which might *not* be an option for free consumer products. You might ask the author what utility was used: it likely was a high-end (read "dear") publishing suite such as [Adobe Illustrator](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/turn-a-boring-bar-graph-into-a-3d-masterpiece--vector-537).

[image: LibreOffice Calc Chart Wizard]